# How to connect HC-05 to MSP430

Tags: raspberry-pi, msp430

I am trying to use Bluetooth module HC-05 with MSP430 by Texas Instrunments. 
I want the bluetooth module to collect data wirelessly from an android phone via bluetooth. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You will find an answer and the end. But first I need to write a few introducing words.

You are new to SO and, you might wonder why no one answered your question.
If I should guess: IMHO there could be two main reasons for this.

1. Your question is not specific enough:

   - What kind of TI MSP430 do you intend to use? I suppose you use a launchpad G2(?).
   - What have you tried so far? You can not expect someone else to invest some time if you did not try so solve your problem yourself. Perhaps it easy, if you only try. The people here love to help, but they expect you to be interested in the problem.
   - What is your backgroud: Are you a programmer but do not know how to connect the hc05 to the MSP or are you fit in electronics and connecting MCUs? Are you a complete beginner?
     There are so much cases and I would not have the time to handle all.
2. I used google to search "MSP430 HC-05" and found a lot of usefull stuff. The first hit is a project working with a Energia IDE, a HC-05 module, a G2-Launchpad and even an Android phone. I and probably other people do not understand why you did not try to search the internet for information.

Ok! enough wise words! ;-)

Here is the promised answer:

You find an example project with the following URL: http://www.electronicwings.com/ti-launchpad/hc-05-bluetooth-module-interfacing-with-msp-exp430g2-ti-launchpad

More results can be found: including (Youtube) Videos
 - Keywords: HC-05 MSP430

Please try to work with that material and feel free to ask furter questions here.
But please be sure to be a bit more specific. (Code examples, error messages, your configuration and hardware and what you've tried so far.)

Cheers PPK